# oracle plsql complex statement inside if condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the pl/sql code i have a variable that grabs the designation_code from a table of a specific employee.

STMT#1

```
select basic_designation into source_designation 
  from tbl_emp_basic_profile where basic_id=source_id;
```

now I need to check if `source_designation` is in a set of codes or not. the {set of codes} can be generated by the following sql:

STMT#2

```
select distinct(BASIC_DESIGNATION) as "SET_OF_CODES" 
  from TBL_EMP_BASIC_PROFILE 
 where BASIC_DESIGNATION in (select to_number(SD_DESIGNATION_CODE)
                       from TBL_SETTINGS_DESIGNATION 
                      where lower(SD_DESIGNATION_NAME) like '%professor%' 
                         or lower(SD_DESIGNATION_NAME) like '%lecturer%');
```

how do I do it? Could I simply write an IF statement like the following?

```
IF(source_designation in (STMT#2)) then
    --do somtehing  
END IF;
```

Comment: Why don't you add the condition in your `WHERE` clause? Like this: `select 1 into v_exists from ... where ... AND BASIC_DESIGNATION = source_designation`. `v_exists` will return 0 if not found else will return value greater than 0 based on the matches found.

Comment: yah now i added the second statement as a `where` clause of the 1st statement. thanks it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way.

1) declare collection 
2) fetch all values into collection from sql.
3) Check if your value is in collection.

Example.

```
    declare 
     type T_SET_OF_CODES is table of varchar2(xxx); -- where xxx is appropriate size of varchar2 for  size_of_codes
     V_SET_OF_CODES T_SET_OF_CODE;
    begin 


    select distinct(BASIC_DESIGNATION) as "SET_OF_CODES" bulk collect into V_SET_OF_CODES
      from TBL_EMP_BASIC_PROFILE 
     where BASIC_DESIGNATION in (select to_number(SD_DESIGNATION_CODE)
                           from TBL_SETTINGS_DESIGNATION 
                          where lower(SD_DESIGNATION_NAME) like '%professor%' 
                             or lower(SD_DESIGNATION_NAME) like '%lecturer%');  

    IF source_designation  member of V_SET_OF_CODES then
        --do somtehing             
    END IF;

    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have written it this way , using the exists to avoid extra scannings, and a count to avoid exception handling.

```
select count(1) 
  into designation_is_in_set
  from dual 
where exists (select 1 from TBL_SETTINGS_DESIGNATION 
 where to_number(SD_DESIGNATION_CODE)=source_designation 
   and (
       lower(SD_DESIGNATION_NAME) like '%professor%' 
    or lower(SD_DESIGNATION_NAME) like '%lecturer%'
       )
  );  
if designation_is_in_set=1 then
  -- the des is in the set
else
  -- the des is not in the set
end if;
```